# Wave equation general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Solve : $$u_{xx}+u_{xt}-20u_{tt} = 0 ,~~~~~ u(x,0) = \phi(x), u_t(x,0) = \psi(x)$$

Well, I looked through the answer and am stuck at one very important part:
The answer assumed i know how to derive the general solution for this type of question: First, i factorize and get 
$$\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}+5\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}-4\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)u = 0$$

And I am confused on how to derive that the general solution which is the following : $$u(x,t) = f(x+\frac{1}{4}t)+g(x-\frac{1}{5}t)$$

I looked through the proof of general solution of the wave equation and was unable to mimic it. Please help.

Comment: what was the general solution?

Comment: Sorry i will correct the grammar mistake, the general solution is the one I wrote above

Comment: Now substitute $f(ax+bt)$ in the PDE and proceed. This is D'Alembert method........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $$w=(\partial_x -4\partial_t)u.$$

Then solve

$$\left[\partial_x+5\partial_t\right]w=0$$

by the method of characteristics.

Then solve

$$w=\left[\partial_x -4\partial_t\right]u,$$

in which $w$ is now a known function.